sqlalchemy contains_eager not loading nested relationships
I have tables of motor and motor_cycle, which is a one to many relationship. I would like to join these tables and show all the motor_cycles for a motor with an OPTIONAL condition on the motor_cycle table. Originally I was using joinedload but found after applying the where condition it would just return all records. I then switched to contains_eager but there is some unusual behavior. When I pass in my filter condition it seems to apply correctly and return one motor_cycle record. But when I don't pass in any condition, instead of returning all the motor_cycle records it just returns one. The one it returns seems to be the same everytime and it doesn't match the condition I had used previously (Not that it matters). What can I do differently to load all the motor_cycle records into my response but at the same time be able to optionally filter them.
EDIT: I've narrowed down the issue to the limit being applied. When sending in my request I am passing in a limit of 1. However this limit should be applied to the parent object not the children. Instead of applying the limit of 1 to motor it is applying it to the motor_cycle. Any idea on how to fix that?
async def search_motors(
    session: AsyncSession,
    serial_number: str = None,
    is_latest_fl: str = None,
    limit: int = 20,
    offset: int = 0,
):
    async with session:

        statement = (
            select(
                DBMotor,
            ).options(contains_eager(DBMotor.motor_cycle))
            .join(DBMotor.motor_cycle)
        )

        if serial_number:
            statement = statement.where(
                DBMotor.serial_number.ilike(f"%{serial_number}%")
            )

        if is_latest_fl:
            statement = statement.where(DBMotorCycle.is_latest_fl == is_latest_fl)

     

        statement = statement.limit(limit).offset(offset)
        result = await session.scalars(statement)
        list_of_motors = result.unique().all()
        list_of_motor_models = (
            [MotorSearchModel.model_validate(motor) for motor in list_of_motors]
            if list_of_motors
            else None
        )

    return list_of_motor_models


I've narrowed down the issue to the limit being applied. When sending in my request I am passing in a limit of 1. However this limit should be applied to the parent object not the children. Instead of applying the limit of 1 to motor it is applying it to the motor_cycle. Any idea on how to fix that?

The issue was not with eager_loading but rather with the limit and how it was being applied in the statement. The limit instead of being applied to the parent object of motor was being applied to the child, motor.
I used a subquery to first fetch the motor records with limit applied and then use that to join to the rest of my query. Below is the final code.
async def search_motors(
    session: AsyncSession,
    serial_number: str = None,
    is_latest_fl: str = None,
    limit: int = 20,
    offset: int = 0,
):
    async with session:
        
        subquery = select(DBMotor).limit(limit).offset(offset).subquery()
        statement = (
            select(
                DBMotor,
            ).options(contains_eager(DBMotor.motor_cycle))
            .join(DBMotor.motor_cycle).outerjoin(subquery, DBMotor.motor_id == subquery.c.motor_id)
        )

        if serial_number:
            statement = statement.where(
                DBMotor.serial_number.ilike(f"%{serial_number}%")
            )

        if is_latest_fl:
            statement = statement.where(DBMotorCycle.is_latest_fl == is_latest_fl)

     

        result = await session.scalars(statement)
        list_of_motors = result.unique().all()
        list_of_motor_models = (
            [MotorSearchModel.model_validate(motor) for motor in list_of_motors]
            if list_of_motors
            else None
        )

    return list_of_motor_models

